# Unable to convert HDFS from non-HA to HA

Tags: high-availability, hadoop, hdfs, zookeeper, cloudera

**Introduction**

**Aim:** Convert HDFS from non-HA to HA.

**Method:** According to [this documentation](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera-content/cloudera-docs/CDH4/latest/CDH4-High-Availability-Guide/cdh4hag_topic_2_4.html) it should be possible to convert HFDS from non- to HA by implementing following configuration:

/etc/hadoop/conf/hdfs-site.xml

```
 <property>
   <name>dfs.ha.automatic-failover.enabled</name>
   <value>true</value>
 </property>
```

/etc/hadoop/conf/core-site.xml

```
 <property>
   <name>ha.zookeeper.quorum</name>
   <value>localhost:2181</value>
 </property>
```

and executing following commands:

`sudo service hadoop-hdfs-journalnode start`

`sudo service hadoop-hdfs-zkfc start`

`hdfs namenode -initializeSharedEdits`

`sudo -u hdfs hdfs namenode -bootstrapStandby`

`sudo service hadoop-hdfs-namenode start`

**Results:**

```
14/06/09 15:37:15 FATAL namenode.NameNode: Exception in namenode join
java.io.IOException: org.apache.hadoop.HadoopIllegalArgumentException: HA is not enabled for this namenode.
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.ha.BootstrapStandby.run(BootstrapStandby.java:310)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.createNameNode(NameNode.java:1154)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.main(NameNode.java:1241)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.HadoopIllegalArgumentException: HA is not enabled for this namenode.
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.ha.BootstrapStandby.parseConfAndFindOtherNN(BootstrapStandby.java:261)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.ha.BootstrapStandby.run(BootstrapStandby.java:92)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:84)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.ha.BootstrapStandby.run(BootstrapStandby.java:305)
        ... 2 more
14/06/09 15:37:15 INFO util.ExitUtil: Exiting with status 1
14/06/09 15:37:15 INFO namenode.NameNode: SHUTDOWN_MSG:
/************************************************************
SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down NameNode at localhost/127.0.0.1
************************************************************/
```

**Question**

How to convert HDFS from non-HA to HA?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After applying the configuration (see Configuration details paragraph) defined in [this documentation](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.3.0/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/HDFSHighAvailabilityWithQJM.html) the issue `HA is not enabled for this namenode` was solved.

```
<property>
  <name>dfs.namenode.rpc-address.mycluster.nn1</name>
  <value>machine1.example.com:8020</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>dfs.namenode.rpc-address.mycluster.nn2</name>
  <value>machine2.example.com:8020</value>
</property>
```

Applying the other configuration settings on respectively the ActiveNN and StandyNN converted HDFS from non-HA to HA.

Answer (score 0):

For me the error `HA is not enabled for this namenode` was resolved when I corrected the hdfs-site.xml config file, where I had mistakenly mentioned 3 namenode-id for a single nameservice-id.

[Ha configuration accepts only 2 namenode-ids.](http://hashprompt.blogspot.in/search/label/Hadoop)